# Git "InvalidGitRepositoryError"

Tags: python, git, compiler-errors

I am supposed to analyze the results of a paper, here is the link for the provided code https://github.com/xiat0616/pseudo-healthy-synthesis

In the file run.py, I am facing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pseudo-healthy-synthesis/run.py", line 76, in <module>
    exper = experiment(comet_exp)
  File "pseudo-healthy-synthesis/run.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/git/repo/base.py", line 181, in __init__
    raise InvalidGitRepositoryError(epath)
git.exc.InvalidGitRepositoryError: /content
```

The error is generated from this instruction

```
git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
```

This is my first time working with Git in python and I don't know how to solve this problem. (I am using gitpython-3.1.13)

Comment: Have you cloned the repository?

Comment: In any case, please try to provide something like a [mcve]. Also, have you searched for the error message or looked at the code raising it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a path to a git repository to the `git.Repo` function:

```
git.Repo(repo, search_parent_directories=True)
```

Comment: working solution

Answer (score 0):

Modify the GitPython package version to 3.1.24

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.